# Nested variables in liquid template don't render. to_liquid?

Tags: liquid

I am using liquid templates but cannot figure out how to render nested variables.  Here's an example where I expect the user's first name to be printed but it is not.  The user object is an ActiveRecord::Base object and has an attribute of `first_name`.  The user object needs to have a `#to_liquid` method but I can't figure out what should go inside of it (tried a hash, setting instance variables, and a struct).

```
user = User.find(1)
template = Liquid::Template.parse('Hello {{ user.first_name }}!')
template.render('user' => user)
#=> "Hello !"
```

My best bet with the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_liquid
    { email: email }
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 #variables you want to expose for liquid template
 liquid_methods :email, :first_name
 ...
end
```